# Not able to figure out invalid syntax error

Tags: python

Misty is fond of pokemons and likes to collect pokemon cards. She has P pokemon cards with her at present. She wants to have a particular number of cards on the Dth day. Her friend Ash is ready to help her to achieve the number. Ash will provide her N cards daily so that a day before the Dth day, she will have the required number of Pokemon cards.

Input Format
The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T

The only line of each test case consists of three space-separated integers, P, N and D.

Constraints
1<= T <=100

1<= D <=100000

0 <= P, N <=100000

Output Format
For each test case, print the required answer in a separate line.

Sample TestCase 1

Input

2

5 4 6

2 2 2

Output

25

4

For the above question I have written the following code

```
def main():
  n=int(input())
  for i in range(n):
      li=list(int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' '))
      P=li[0]
      N=li[1]
      D=li[2]
      for i in range(D-1):
         mul=(D-1)*N
      ans=mul+P
 return ans


main()
```

After compiling I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "CandidateCode.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()

  File "CandidateCode.py", line 5, in main

  li=list(int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' '))

  File "<string>", line 1

  5 4 6

   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the invalid syntax here?

Comment: Maybe you should add a code indent after `def main():` line?

Comment: @baldr it is there still it gives error

Comment: If you're using python 2 then that's the problem

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen why?

Comment: @manasvi.jain see my answer

Comment: because `input()` in Python 2 treats `5 4 6` as code and it tries to execute it - but `5 4 6` is not valid code. In Python 2 you have to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: Read [documentation of Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) and study for inspiration open source code written in Python, e.g. on http://github.com/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using Python 2 which is the cause of the problem.

The `input()` in python 2 accept a command itself not just string, you need it to be `'5 6 7'` rather than `5 6 7` which is Python 3 syntax.

In python 2 you can

```
>>> a = input()
2
```

And `a` will be an `int` instead of `string` like in Python 3.

Enter `5 6 7` in python 2 is like `a = 5 6 7` and obviously it will error.

Comment: One additional message to the asker: 2 has reached end-of-life several months ago and is not longer supported. This date was announced over 10 years ago. You really want to switch to Python 3 now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    n=int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        li=list(int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' '))
        P=li[0]
        N=li[1]
        D=li[2]
        for i in range(D-1):
            mul=(D-1)*N
        ans=mul+P
    return ans
main()
```